# How to reach external js's methods or objects in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I want to add external js (with cdn) but i cant reach methods.

I added to mounted hook like (i don't think it is the best practice):

```
mounted() {
let leafMap = document.createElement("script");
leafMap.setAttribute(
  "src",
  "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
);
document.head.appendChild(leafMap);
}
```

I can reach from vue methods like:

```
window.L //window.<packageName>
```

But `window.L` is undefined when page created. So i should wait script to load. How can i handle the process?

Comment: https://qastack.ru/programming/45047126/how-to-add-external-js-scripts-to-vuejs-components

Comment: I did a quick search.  I haven't used this, but you may want to take a look at [Vue2Leaflet](https://github.com/vue-leaflet/Vue2Leaflet).

Comment: Leaflet was a example. It can also be the case for any cdn js library

Answer (score 1):

The `created` hook occurs before the `mounted` hook, where you've added the script, so `window.L` wouldn't be available there.

The script will have already run upon the `load` event, so you could add a `load`-event handler where you could use `window.L`:

```js
let leafMap = document.createElement("script");
leafMap.setAttribute(/*...*/);
leafMap.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log("L", window.L);
});
document.head.appendChild(leafMap);
```